# How to customize many-to-many field in the form, using Symfony2 or Symfony 3 ?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, many-to-many

Symfony 2, Symfony 3. How to change the way the many-to-many relation is displayed in form? For example, how to display many-to-many relation entities ids in a row with checkboxes, instead of default column of checkboxes?

Could anyone refer to an example form?

I have tried in the twig template:

```
{% for admin in form.admins %} 

{{ admin.username  }} //gives error that method GetUsername is not found

{{ form_widget(form.offsetGet(admin.username))  }}, //gives error that method GetUsername is not found

{% endfor %}
```

The EventType.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;

class EventType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add( 'title', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => 'title', ) )
            ->add( 'keywords', 'text', array(  
                 'attr' => array('style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => 'keyow',) )
            ->add( 'zip', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => 'zip', ) )
            ->add( 'latitude', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => 'latitude', ) )
            ->add( 'longitude', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => 'longitude', ) )
            ->add( 'starttimeInt', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) )
            ->add( 'endtimeInt', 'hidden', array('data' => '0',) ) 
            ->add( 'starttimeStr', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => '21-12-2015 4:15 Europe/London', ) )
            ->add( 'endtimeStr', 'text', array(  
                'attr' => array( 'style' => 'width: 500px',), 'data' => '21-12-2015 4:15 Europe/London', ) )                
            ->add( 'address', 'textarea',  array(
                                'label' => 'Address starting with post code', 
                                'data' => 'BR13RX',
                                'attr' => array( 'rows' => 2, 'cols' =>80, ), ) )
            ->add( 'details', 'textarea',  array(
                                'label' => 'Details',
                                'data' => 'x',
                                'attr' => array( 'rows' => 20, 'cols' =>80, ),
                                'max_length' => '5000' )) 
            ->add( 'contacts', 'textarea',  array(
                                'label' => 'Contact methods',
                                'data' => 'x',
                                'attr' => array( 'rows' => 4, 'cols' =>80, ),
                                'max_length' => '4000' )  )
            ->add( 'admins', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'MeetingBundle\Entity\User',
                        'property' => 'username',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => true  ) )
            ->add( 'attendees', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'MeetingBundle\Entity\User',
                        'property' => 'username',
                        'multiple' => true,
                        'expanded' => true  ) ) ;  
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'MeetingBundle\Entity\Event'));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'meetingbundle_event';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap (e.g., [braincrafted](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/)) you can add to the form field definition: `'attr' => ['class' => 'form-inline',],`

Answer (score 0):

You can customize everything you need with form themes, just read the doc carefully: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html